# One Windows 10 Client Logs Into Windows Server 2012 R2 Other Win 10 Client Doesn't

Tags: windows, authentication

I have read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018) advisory mentioned in the error I get when my client tries to log into our server.

[image]

It is a CredSSP error trying to log into a Windows 2012 Server R2 that Win 8 and Win 7 clients can log into. Another Win 10 client can also log into the same server.

The problem seems like there is a setting on my workstation that needs to change, but I cannot tell what to set.

By the way, all these servers, including the one I cannot log into, as well as all the clients trying to connect are behind a firewall.

I would appreciate any advice on what to check. Also, I am fully updated with Microsoft Windows updates.

Comment: The link from the error message might be useful. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018 . Try updating your servers and workstations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, I am fully updated with Microsoft Windows updates.

You may be, but this server may not. There is a [compatibility matrix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-en/help/4093492) which works with which and the registry setting you can use to modify you servers behaviour.

You can try to set the *AllowEncryptionOracle* DWORD in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters` to "2".

Comment: What s/he said.  We ran into this recently.  You need to make sure the *server* is current on patches.  This resolved the issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the Windows 10 client that is failing is on Win 10 build 1803 and TSpkg.dll in %Windir%\System32 is at File version 10.0.17134.48.

If these are not true then you are incorrect about having all relevant updates installed.  Review the update links mentioned in [MS KB 4295591](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4295591/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-when-to-rdp-to-azure-vm)